# Why was the bounty awarded in this way?

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer

I asked this question on SO:

[What are the advantages and disadvantages of the require vs. import methods of loading code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849376/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-the-require-vs-import-methods-of-lo)

I didn't manually accept any answers, but for some reason, one of the lesser answers was auto-selected as the accepted answer.  I was expecting the top answer to get accepted.  Why?  And can this be changed, I really don't want the answer that was accepted to be the accepted answer.  kaizer.se's answer was much, much better.

**Edit:**
Is there any way to have a moderator come through and change the accepted answer to kaiser.se's?  If I'd known about that second condition, I would have manually accepted.  I didn't want to discourage new answerers from commenting though, so I was going to let it auto-accept.

Incidentally, the rule about only auto-accepting answers posted after the bounty begins is... truly daft, IMHO.  I can understand that one might make the assumption that a bounty was started because the questioner was dissatisfied with all current answers, and thus none of them should be auto-accepted, but honestly, I can't think of even one instance where I've started a bounty with that in mind.  When I start a bounty, it's because I'm dissatisfied with the breadth of the answers presented.  I may already be happy with an answer given, but it's usually for a question that's subjective enough that more discussion is desired.

Comment: Why didn't you manually accept an answer if there was one you liked?

Comment: I knew it! random is a bounty hunter!

Comment: Note that even if the desired post *had* won the bounty by default, they would only have got half the points... if you *like* an answer, **accept** it.

Comment: @Marc: Sure, I know that *now*.  Perhaps the bounty system should explain the ramifications of setting a bounty a bit better.  As I wrote above, I didn't want to discourage additional participation by accepting the best answer early.

Comment: Also, perhaps the "Hey, the bounty is ending soon!" message should sound a bit scarier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an auto-accept feature on bounties. This much I think you knew. However, it works a little funky -- it can only auto-accept the top-voted answer which meets both of the following criteria:

- Must have at least **+2** upvotes
- Must have been posted *after* the bounty was initiated (likely why the 12-score answer didn't get accepted)

Note that it's possible for a bounty to expire with no answers meeting said criteria, in which case none are selected as the accepted answer, and in fact no answer can *ever* be accepted.

Generally, it's recommended that bounty users manually accept the one they feel is most worthy.

See also:

- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Bah, yeah, the second thing was what did it.  His answer was the first one that was submitted, and it was before the bounty was started.